# Wordpress Google Site kit - Configuration with different projects

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I have a wordpress project that's online that is setted with Site Kit Plugin. I have created a new wordpress project that will replace the old one. My doubt is: If I will bring the new project to the configured domain, settings will be the same or I have to configure everything again?

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is changing, you should [reset Site Kit](https://sitekit.withgoogle.com/documentation/using-site-kit/reset/) before migrating. This is to ensure no incorrect site records exist on the new domain. Without resetting it's possible that when the plugin performs lookup for data on the old domain.

Even if you don't reset, the plugin will likely recognize a URL change although there are various ways to migrate a site and some can cause issues.

Note also that you can connect Site Kit to the same Google Analytics property on your new domain also. If your domain name on the new site is not based off the current site, you may have to create a new Search Console property.

If you run into any questions you can reach out in the Site Kit plugin support forums.